# Testing the quality of PRNGs

Tags: random, montecarlo, mersenne-twister

I am playing around with PRNGs (like Mersenne Twister and `rand()` function of stdlib) and I would want a good test that would help me ascertain the quality of random data produced by the PRNGs.
I have calculated the value of Pi using random numbers generated by the PRNGs, and I find `rand()` and Mersenne Twister to be very close to offer a distinction (do I need to scrutinize after 10 decimal points?).

I do not have much idea about Monte Carlo simulations; please let me know about some algorithm/application (possibly something simple yet which could provide good inferences) that would help me distinguish them in terms of quality.

---

**EDIT 1:** I didn't notice before, but there is a similar thread: [How to test random numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778718/how-to-test-random-numbers)

**EDIT 2:** I am not able to interprete the results of NIST, as mentioned in one of the comments. I got this idea of visually interpreting the pattern (if any) from [random.org](http://www.random.org/analysis/) and am following that because of it's simplicity. I would be very glad if someone could comment on the process of my testing:

1. Generate N randoms from [0,1] using rand() and MT1997
2. if `(round(genrand_real1() / rand_0_1()))` then red pixel, else black

As I understand that this is not a very precise solution, but if this provides a reasonable estimate, then I could live with this at the present moment.

Comment: i'm not so sure about getting any **random data** from **pseudorandom number generators** - but i think you could implement http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_coin#Fair_results_from_a_biased_coin with them..

Comment: are you saying that because the values generated from PRNGs are predictable? thank you

Comment: yes, that is the distinction - it was just a reminder for you to check whether a PRNG is good enought for your application and you don't need a TRNG like [random.org](http://random.org)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two standard test suites for testing random numbers.

1. [NIST](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/index.html) test suite. They have an [implementation in C.](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/stats_tests.html)
2. [Diehard Test Suite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) (developed by George Marsaglia). There is a [C library](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php) implementation of these tests.

There is a R interface to the Dieharder library, called [RDieHarder](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rdieharder.html). This library provides an interface to both the NIST and Diehard test suites.

Comment: I am using NIST, but I think although my test passes, there's some problem; can you please help? - I have generated long random values, and converted them to binary and stored in a file. Say 100 randoms are there in the file, I do assess 100 and follow the steps in the "Running the Test Code" section of the doc (chose the bit streams generated to be 10 as in the doc). But I see that my "finalAnalysisReport.txt" for the default test case contains almost no info.

Comment: Your best bet is to ask another question.

Comment: This answer was good, but is outdated now. See the other answer for an update (TL;DR: L'Ecuyer's TestU01, or PractRand).

Answer (score 13):

There are several statistical tests suites available.  I wrote, copied, and otherwise gathered together 120 PRNGs and tested each with a variety of tests suites given 4 hours per PRNG per test suite:

- [PractRand](http://pracrand.sourceforge.net/) (standard, 1 terabyte) found bias in 78 PRNGs
- [TestU01](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html) (BigCrush) found bias in 50 PRNGs
- [RaBiGeTe](http://cristianopi.altervista.org/RaBiGeTe_MT/) (extended, 512 megabit, x1) found bias in 40 PRNGs
- [Dieharder](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php) (custom command line options) found bias in 25 PRNGs
- [Dieharder](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php) (-a command line option) found bias in 13 PRNGs
- [NIST STS](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documentation_software.html) (default, 64 megabit x128) found bias in 11 PRNGs

**How many of those were in PRNGs that the other test suites all missed?**

- PractRand (standard, 1 terabyte) found 22 unique biases, in a wide variety of categories.
- RaBiGeTe (extended, 512 megabit, x1) found 5 unique biases, all in LCGs and combination LCGs.
- TestU01 BigCrush found 2 unique biases, both in small chaotic PRNGs.
  No other test suite found any unique biases.

**In short, only PractRand, TestU01, and possibly RaBiGeTe are worth using.**

*Full disclosure: I wrote PractRand, so either the set of PRNGs or any other non-qualitative measure could be biased in its favor.*

**Miscellaneous advantages:**

- PractRand and TestU01 tend to be the easiest to interpret the output of in my opinion.
- PractRand and Dieharder tend to be the easiest to automate testing for via command line interface I think.
- PractRand and RaBiGeTe were the only ones to support multithreaded testing.

**Miscellaneous disadvantages:**

- PractRand required more bits of input to test than other test suites - could be a problem if your RNG is very slow or otherwise limited on amount of data produced.
- RaBiGeTe and NIST STS both have interface issues.
- Dieharder and NIST STS both have false-positive issues.
- NIST STS had the worst interface in my opinion.
- I could not get Dieharder to compile on Windows. I managed to get TestU01 to compile on windows but it took some work.
- Recent versions of RaBiGeTe are closed-source and windows-only.

**The set of PRNGs tested:**
The PRNG set includes 1 large GFSR, 1 large LFSR, 4 xorshift type PRNGs, 2 xorwow type PRNGs, 3 other not-quite-LFSR PRNGs. It includes 10 simple power-of-2 modulus LCGs (which discard low bits to reach acceptable quality levels), 10 power-of-2 modulus not-quite-LCGs, and 9 combination generators based primarily around LCGs and not-quite-LCGs. It includes 19 reduced strength versions of CSPRNGs, plus one full strength CSPRNG. Of those, 14 were based upon indirection / dynamic s-boxes (e.g. RC4, ISAAC), four were ChaCha/Salsa parameterizations, and the remaining 2 were Trivium variants. It includes 11 PRNGs broadly classifiable as LFib-type or similar, not counting the LFSRs/GFSRs. The rest (about 35) were small state chaotic PRNGs, of which 10 used multiplication and the others were limited to arithmetic and bitwise logic.

**Edit:** There is also the test set in [gjrand](http://gjrand.sourceforge.net/), which is very obscure and a little odd, but actually does extremely well.

Also, all of the PRNGs tested are included as non-recommended PRNGs in PractRand.

Comment: I'm happy to recommend your answer, however, as written there is no evidence. Can you provide links to papers, that back up your claim? Or a some instructions on how to repeat your experiments.

Comment: No evidence whatsoever! DieHarder has around 106 tests. PractRand and TestU01 are written in C and C++ and require the user to integrate their generator!
The easiest ever to use so far are DieHarder (ubuntu package) and NIST STS (python UI and implementation)!  I strongly believe you're biased to your work and indeed as @csgillespie mentioned in his comment, you need to provide a paper that supports your claims though!

Answer (score 0):

You're best off looking into the [volume 2 of the Knuth's series](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Art-Computer-Programming-Seminumerical-Algorithms/dp/0201896842).

For a shorter read, look up the corresponding chapter of the Numerical Recipes.

If you're only interested in a sort of a baseline for a MC simulation--- linear congruential generators are best avoided, Mersenne Twister is *good enough* in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Can you give a link to evidence for the claim that LGCs are best avoided for Monte-Carlo simulations?

Comment: @ziggystar: well, you can look up in Knuth. Or Numerical Recipes. Or google up the results the standard test suites, eg from the csgillespie answer.