# True random number generator (TRNG), Haskell and an empirical / formal method

Tags: haskell, random, arduino, serial-port, trng

I want to produce verifications to a true random number generator (TRNG) numbers generated by specific hardware, but I'm not used to this.

Firstly, I want to test the consistency of the True Random Number Generator (TRNG) via empiric methods ([AKA](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AKA), I want to check if they are really true random numbers (TRNs)); and I don't know if I can check this with formal methods.

Are there some specific lectures on this topic? What about some tips? Are there tools for this empiric method testing?

Comment: Did you mean TRNG instead of PRNG in the second paragraph?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/778754/1598537). Distinguishing Pseudo Random from Random is very tricky. Build on others' solutions. Look up NIST and diehard to start with.

Comment: As with the last time you asked this, could you clarify what it means to you to use formal methods to verify a PRNG?  You could mean so many things such as "verify it matches a high-level description of the RNG algorithm" or "verify the output passes a randomness test or is inhibited" or so many other things.  Also, do you know about the language Cryptol?

Comment: @AndrewC oh yes! I edited the question properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that you not try to duplicate existing tools, since it would be a lot of work.  Marsaglia's [Diehard tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) should work, or you can use [dieharder](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php), which is a GPL reimplementation.  From the webpage:

> The primary point of dieharder (like diehard before it) is to make it easy to time and test (pseudo)random number generators, both software and hardware, for a variety of purposes in research and cryptography. The tool is built entirely on top of the GSL's random number generator interface and uses a variety of other GSL tools (e.g. sort, erfc, incomplete gamma, distribution generators) in its operation.